# Cant render my image on my canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I cant seem to render an image that I have onto my canvas. For some reason it just doesnt show up. Ive looked online for solutions, but none of them work.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Battlefield Online</title>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1800" height="800"></canvas>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">


//Socket io connection
    var socket = io();
//Grabing canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 39) {// right arrow
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: true});
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 37) {// left arrow
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: true});
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 38) {// up arrow
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: true});
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 32) {// space
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'space', state: true});
  }
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 39) {// right arrow
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'right', state: false});
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 37) {// left arrow
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'left', state: false});
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 38) {// up arrow
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'up', state: false});
  }
  else if(event.keyCode === 32) {// space
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: 'space', state: false});
  }
}



socket.on('newPosistions', function(data){

  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){        
    context.drawImage(img,0,0, 100, 100); 
  };  
  img.src = "2d-game-bg.jpg";

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba('+ data[i].color[0] +', '+ data[i].color[1] +', '+ data[i].color[2] +', 1)';
    context.fillRect(data[i].x, data[i].y, 50, 100);
  }
});



</script>
```

The part where I draw the image is at the bottom, in the socket.on('newPo...
This should work as Ive followed tutorials and examples exactly which have worked and none of them seem to work for me.

I have loaded the image with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="2d-game-bg.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
</script>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The canvas tag is not supported in Internet 
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is an exact copy of a w3schools tutorial. It works for my image, so it does exist and the server isn't having an issue rendering it.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Well one problem is that your canvas element is in the head area, which is incorrect.  It should be in the body area.  I'm not sure if thats the only problem, but it certainly needs fixed.

Comment: @lancew Ahh right. Thanks. Ill change that and see what happens.